# Is there a way to compress output in kohana?

Tags: php, gzip, kohana, kohana-3

Well, i guess there are some ways to gzip html. Add
`ob_start('ob_gzhandler');` to index.php or in the main app controller. But i hope there is a better solution. In addition i want it applied to all text outputs, i.e. css, js like it was back in CI. Maybe a module or something? Or the only way is to overwrite View::capture method and other methods in HTML-class?
Using kohana 3.2, pretty much newbie.
Oh, and i don't want to use htaccess for that. If it's possible of course.
Thanx in advance

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using gzip compression in your webserver.

Comment: It seems like there is no other way. Simple, but i liked how it was in CI.